# FLASK, date and time in the same db column

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

im doing a simple work in flask, i have a problem, i have this db table (sqlalchemy)

```
class Event(db.Model, UserMixin):
Number = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
Name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
Organiser = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
Position = db.Column(db.String(20), db.ForeignKey(Position.Zone), nullable=False)
Date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
Number_of_entrance = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
Ticket_price = db.Column(db.Integer)
Typology = db.Column(db.String(20))
```

i want to get time and data from 2 different forms and put both into Date column.

this is the class forms

```
class EventForm(FlaskForm):
name = StringField(validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)],
                   render_kw={"placeholder": "Name Event"})
organiser = StringField(validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)],
                   render_kw={"placeholder": "Organiser"})
position = StringField(validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)],
                   render_kw={"placeholder": "Zone"})
data = DateField(render_kw={"placeholder": "Data"})
time = TimeField(validators=[InputRequired()], render_kw={"placeholder": "Time"})

numberentrance = IntegerField(validators=[InputRequired()],
                   render_kw={"placeholder": "Number of Entrace"})

price = IntegerField(validators=[InputRequired()],
                   render_kw={"placeholder": "Ticket price"})
typology = StringField(validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)],
                   render_kw={"placeholder": "Typology"})
submit = SubmitField("Create Event")
```

and this is the function for put them into db

```
def newevent():
from model import Event
form = EventForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    event = Event(Name=form.name.data, Organiser=form.organiser.data,Date=(form.data.data,form.time.data)
                  Position=form.position.data,
                  Number_of_entrance=form.numberentrance.data, Ticket_price=form.price.data,
                  Typology=form.typology.data)


    flash('Event created!', 'success')
    db.session.add(event)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
return render_template('create_event/index.html', form=form)
```

how can do it? thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [datetime.combine()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) to combine a `date` and a `time` into a `datetime`:

```
>>> from datetime import date, time, datetime
>>> d = date(2022, 1, 17)
>>> d
datetime.date(2022, 1, 17)
>>> t = time(6, 47)
>>> t
datetime.time(6, 47)
>>> dt = datetime.combine(d, t)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 17, 6, 47)
```